OutOfMemoryException on WIA Duplex Scan with Epson DS-410
I'm wrinting an programm to scan documents with my Epson Scanner DS-410. With the first atempt using the Twain Interface everything works as expected.
Now I added the Support for WIA and got problems with the duplex mode. As long as I scan only one side (duplexActive is false) everything works fine. But when I activate duplex mode (duplexActive is true) I get a OutOfMemoryException after calling ShowTransfer(). The scanner seems to scan the page but when it's finished the Exception is thrown.
Here is the part of teh code that does the actual scan:
if(documentHandlingSelect != null)
        {
          int handlingValue = 0;
          if(feederActivate)
            handlingValue |= (int)WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT.FEEDER;
          if(duplexActive)
            handlingValue |= (int)WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT.DUPLEX;

          documentHandlingSelect.set_Value(handlingValue);
        }

        //if(!duplexActive)
          SetWIAProperty(device.Properties, WIA_DPS_PAGES, 1);


        WIA.ICommonDialog wiaCommonDialog = new WIA.CommonDialog();

        WIA.ImageFile image = null;

        try
        {
          image = wiaCommonDialog.ShowTransfer(item, WIA_FORMAT_JPEG, true); <=== here I get OutOfMemoryException
          if(image != null)
          {
            // save to temp file
            string fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
            File.Delete(fileName);
            image.SaveFile(fileName);

I tried to set a different number of pages with WIA_DPS_PAGES but only 1 seems to be valid.
Different image formats made no change (WIA_FORMAT_BMP, WIA_FORMAT_JPEG, WIA_FORMAT_TIFF).
I found this but it did not help.
Here I found a description of the same problem but there was no solution.
I also tried a resolution of 50 DPI and only 'BlackAndWhite' mode with the same Exception.
